# How to select a portion of a NumPy array efficiently?

Tags: arrays, matlab, numpy

I'm switching from Matlab/octve to Numpy/Scipy.

To select a segment of a Matlab array, it was quite easy.
e.g.

```
>> x = [1, 2, 3, 4; 5, 6, 7, 8; 9, 10, 11, 12]
x =

     1     2     3     4
     5     6     7     8
     9    10    11    12

>> y = x(2:3, 1:2)

y =

     5     6
     9    10
```

How can the same thing be done with NumPy when

```
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
```

Comment: You can start by taking a look at the numpy documentation on array indexing, [particularly the section on slice indexing](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As [Indexing > Other indexing options](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#other-indexing-options) in the NumPy documentation mentions,

> The slicing and striding works exactly the same way it does for lists and tuples except that they can be applied to multiple dimensions as well.

For your example, this means

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11, 12]])
# array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4],
#        [ 5,  6,  7,  8],
#        [ 9, 10, 11, 12]])

x[1:3, 0:2]
# => array([[ 5,  6],
#           [ 9, 10]])
```

Most notable difference to Matlab is probably that indexing is zero-based (i.e., first element has index `0`) and that index ranges (called 'slices' in Python) are expressed with an exclusive upper bound: `l[4:7]` gets `l[4]`, `l[5]` and `l[6]` (the 3rd to the 7th element), but not `l[7]` (the 8th element).

The [Python tutorial's section on lists](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) will give you a feeling for how indexing and slicing works for normal (1-dimensional) collections.